# Spyder and WinPython plotting problems

Tags: python, plot, spyder

I'm a Python newbie / Matlab-convert, working in a Spyder2.3.0beta2 console with WinPython [1].  When I use the Run file (F5) button to plot the code shown below [2], the first time after starting Sypder it reliably produces a plot that is not brought to the front of the display.  The second time, the code reliably "hangs" in the console [3] until I hit return once, after which the figure is produced but not brought to the front of the display.  The third and later times, the code does not appear to "hang" in the console, but no plot is produced until I hit return ... and then a figure is produced but not brought to the front of the display.

My problem or WinPython's?

Refs:
[1] 
Start up produces:

```
Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 18 2013, 21:19:30) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Imported NumPy 1.8.0, SciPy 0.13.2, SciPy.linalg 0.4.9, Matplotlib 1.3.1
+ guidata 1.6.1, guiqwt 2.3.2
Type "scientific" for more details.
```

[2]

```
close('all')
t = linspace(0, 3, 51)      # 51 points between 0 and 3
y = t**2*exp(-t**2)
plot(t, y)
xlabel('t')
ylabel('y')
legend(['t^2*exp(-t^2)'])
axis([0, 3, -0.05, 0.6]) # [tmin, tmax, ymin, ymax]
title('My First Matplotlib Demo')
show()
```

[3] Displayed in console:

```
>>> runfile('C:/Users/cwilly/Desktop/Python/test_text_file.py', wdir=r'C:/Users/cwilly/Desktop/Python')
```

[4] Displayed in console:

```
>>> runfile('C:/Users/cwilly/Desktop/Python/test_text_file.py', wdir=r'C:/Users/cwilly/Desktop/Python')
>>>
```